# Rolling quantile with xarray

Tags: python, quantile, python-xarray

Is there a `xArray` way of computing quantiles on a `DataArray.rolling` window? The listed available methods include `mean` or `median`, but nothing on quantiles/percentiles. I was wondering if this could be somehow done even though there is no direct way.

Currently, I am locally migrating the `xArray` data to a `pandas.DataFrame`, where I apply the `rolling().quantile()` sequence. After that, I take the values of the new `DataFrame` and build a `xArray.DataArray` from it. The reproducible code:

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

times = np.arange(0, 30)
locs = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] 

signal = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(len(times), len(locs)), 
                      coords=[times, locs], dims=['time', 'locations'])
window = 5

df = pd.DataFrame(data=signal.data)
roll = df.rolling(window=window, center=True, axis=0).quantile(.25).dropna()
window_array = xr.DataArray(roll.values, 
            coords=[np.arange(0, signal.time.shape[0] - window + 1), signal.locations], 
            dims=['time', 'locations'])
```

Any clue to stick to `xArray` as much as possible is welcome.

Let us consider the same problem, only smaller in size (10 time instances, 2 locations).

Here is the input of the first method (via `pandas`):

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 8, locations: 2)>
array([[0.404362, 0.076203],
       [0.353639, 0.076203],
       [0.387167, 0.102917],
       [0.525404, 0.298231],
       [0.755646, 0.298231],
       [0.460749, 0.414935],
       [0.104887, 0.498813],
       [0.104887, 0.420935]])
Coordinates:
* time       (time) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
* locations  (locations) <U1 'A' 'B'
```

Note that the 'time' dimension is smaller, due to calling `dropna()` on the rolling object. The new dimension size is basically `len(times) - window + 1`. Now, the output for the proposed method (via `construct`):

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 10, locations: 2)>
array([[0.438426, 0.127881],
       [0.404362, 0.076203],
       [0.353639, 0.076203],
       [0.387167, 0.102917],
       [0.525404, 0.298231],
       [0.755646, 0.298231],
       [0.460749, 0.414935],
       [0.104887, 0.498813],
       [0.104887, 0.420935],
       [0.112651, 0.60338 ]])
Coordinates:
* time       (time) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
* locations  (locations) <U1 'A' 'B'
```

It seems like the dimensions are still `(time, locations)`, with the size of the former equal to 10, not 8. In the example here, since `center=True`, the two results are the same if you remove the first and the last rows in the second array. Shouldn't the `DataArray` have a new dimension, the `tmp`?

Also, this method (with `bottleneck` installed) takes more than the one initially proposed via `pandas`. For example, on a case study of 1000 `times` x 2 `locations`, the `pandas` run takes 0.015 s, while the `construct` one takes 1.25 s.

Comment: `skipna=False` may speed up the computation, as it can avoid copying the enlarged array. It also makes nan in both the ends. The script may look like `signal.rolling(time=window, center=True).construct('tmp').quantile(.25, dim='tmp', skipna=False).dropna('time')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`construct` method](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/computation.html#rolling-window-operations) of the rolling object, which generates a new `DataArray` with the rolling dimension.

```
signal.rolling(time=window, center=True).construct('tmp').quantile(.25, dim='tmp')
```

Above, I constructed a DataArray with additional `tmp` dimension and compute quantile along this dimension.

Comment: Thank you, @Keisuke FUJII. I have marked it as solved, since it provides a nice work-around for the addition of extra methods to the rolling object. Still, I noticed a few unexpected things in the behavior of this solution, which I will add as an edit to my initial comment.